# Query Complex using Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wirting a query using Django, I have my model:

```
class Recommender(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="recoCustomer")
    brand = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="recoBrand")
    recommender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="recommender")
    authorized = models.ForeignKey(State, default=5,
        help_text=_('Recommend state (5-pending, 6-approved, 2-canceled).'),
    )
    dateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The first requeriment was:

- I need all records where the customer is equal to loggued in user and `authorized` is equal to `5`. My first query was:

  `Recommender.objects.all().filter(
         customer=request.user, authorized=State.objects.get(pk=5)
      )`

However, right now I need all records where the customer is equal to loggued in user and ***authorized*** is equal to 5 , but if exist a couple (***brand_id***, ***customer_id***) where ***authorized*** is equal to 6 , the query must ignore the anothers records of the couple (***brand_id***, ***customer_id***) with ***authorized*** is equal to 5.

---

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
                       Records on table Recommenders
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    | authorized | brand_id | customer_id | recommender_id | dateTime |
    |------------|----------|-------------|----------------|----------|
    | 5          | 1        |32           |31              | ...      |
    | 5          | 1        |32           |19              | ...      |
    | 5          | 9        |32           |8               | ...      |
    | 5          | 28       |32           |8               | ...      |
    | 6          | 1        |32           |8               | ...      |
```

In the previous table, the query should not return records with couple (***brand_id***, ***customer_id***) = (***1***, ***32***), because exist one record with this couple with ***authorized*** equal to `6`.
How Can I to make this query using Django ORM?

Comment: You need [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) .  You can do different `Q()` that take parameters like your `filter()` and then combine them using `&`, `|`, `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of Q()

```
    if query:
        queryset_find = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(FP_Item__contains=query))
        context = {'object_list': queryset_find}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

If you need multiple Queries here is the reference, search within for "multiple"
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/